# custom MarshalText() for golang sql.NULL* types

Tags: go

I am trying to marshal SQL results into JSON in code that is using SQL.NullFloat64 and the https://github.com/kisielk/sqlstruct package.

Ref: https://github.com/kisielk/sqlstruct/issues/11#issuecomment-143400458

This issue is I am getting the

```
{
    "Float64": 141,
    "Valid": true
}
```

result in the JSON not just the value.   Following the advice in the github issue above I tried to make a custom MarshalText() but it never gets called.

The code is at: https://gist.github.com/fils/3f557941d71f1a7165ca

The JSON produced is at: https://gist.github.com/fils/a01cadcbb5dc7c797c3e

The CSV dump function is obtaining and outputting the value only ok, but not sure how to get that effect for the JSON one too.

Using either sql.NullFloat64 or the custom type NullFloat64 give the same results.

Comment: From [ask]: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://play.golang.org/) then do so - but **also include the code in your question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." In this case if the gist goes away this question becomes useless/meaningless. The help center also describes creating a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here I emphasis minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NullFloat64` is not an `encoding.TextMarshaler`. See http://play.golang.org/p/AepGgQkOd7:

```
prog.go:25: cannot use NullFloat64 literal (type NullFloat64) as type encoding.TextMarshaler in assignment:
    NullFloat64 does not implement encoding.TextMarshaler (wrong type for MarshalText method)
        have MarshalText() []byte
        want MarshalText() ([]byte, error)
```

Change your method to

```
func (nf NullFloat64) MarshalText() ([]byte, error) {
    if nf.Valid {
        nfv := nf.Float64
        return []byte(strconv.FormatFloat(nfv, 'f', -1, 64)), nil
    } else {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..  I see the github issue response I got was correct all the time, I just didn't follow it properly.   I appreciate your help.  I ran it and it's all working well now!